# Strange ImageFilter results

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to perform some neighborhood analysis on an image, but ImageFilter seems to be interfering with the results outputted by the provided filtering function.

#### Initialization

Given the hue channel of an image

```
image = Import["http://i.imgur.com/IqnvrjC.png"]
hue = ColorSeparate[image, "HSB"][[1]]
```

We can see that there is some information "hidden" on the dark area

```
ImageAdjust[hue, {0, 0, 0.2}]
```

#### Processing

My intent is to replace the value of every pixel with the value of the variance of his direct (3x3), neighbors:

```
huevar = ImageFilter[Composition[Variance, Flatten], hue, 1]
```

The result is also very dark, as expected, but the dark areas are effectively black. As I haven't clipped the results, it is not what I expected.

The filter outputs small values, as I could observe in the following:

```
Reap[
  huevar = ImageFilter[Composition[Sow[#] &, Variance, Flatten], hue, 1],
   _,
  (reapvar = #2)&
];

reapvar // Take[#, 5] &
(* {0.000126874, 0.000250331, 0.0000807382, 8.11654*10^-6, 0.0000234952} *)

Flatten@ImageData@huevar // Take[#, 5] &
(* {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

If I reconstruct the image with data from `reapvar` I get exactly what I want: a dark image that can be re-scaled to show the detail in the dark area.

```
Image[Partition[reapvar, First@ImageDimensions@image]]
ImageAdjust[%, {0, 0, .1}]
```

#### Pre or mid-scaling

I've also tried pre-scaling the output directly in filtering function, as in

```
Reap[
  scaledhuevar = ImageFilter[Composition[Sow[1000*#] &, Variance, Flatten], hue, 1],
   _,
  (scaledreapvar = #2)&
];
```

The dark areas get brighter this way, but the precise values, even from the bright areas, are different from those obtained by sowing/reaping.

```
scaledreapvar // Take[#, 5] &
(* {0.126874, 0.250331, 0.0807382, 0.00811654, 0.0234952} *)

Flatten@ImageData@scaledhuevar // Take[#, 5] &
(* {0.12549, 0.25098, 0.0823529, 0.00784314, 0.0235294} *)
```

What is causing this difference in the results? When/where is the clipping occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by rounding errors, but the effect is gone if you work with `Real`images:

```
image = Import["http://i.imgur.com/IqnvrjC.png"];
hue = ColorSeparate[image, "HSB"][[1]];
hueR = Image[ImageData@hue, "Real"];

Tr[Subtract@@ (Flatten/@ Reap@ImageData@
                ImageFilter[Sow@Variance@Flatten@#&, #, 1])]& /@ {hue, hueR}

(*
  {-0.748735, 0.}
*)
```